# Netty ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter write

Tags: java, netty

I have a `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` which overrides method `write`. What are the differences between calling parent class `write` method:

```java
public class MyChannelOutboundHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {
    //some code
    super.write(ctx, anotherMessage, promise);
    }
}
```

and calling context `write`?:

```java
public class MyChannelOutboundHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {
    //some code
    ctx.write(anotherMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [source code](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.6.Final/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java#ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.write%28io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cio.netty.channel.ChannelPromise%29) of the `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter#write` to determine this. It is calling a write on context passing both message and promise:

```
@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    ctx.write(msg, promise);
}
```

So first evident difference is `promise` not being passed to context.

The difference in the long term will be:

1. Calling `super` method you are decorating write method. You should do this when you want to add some additional behavior to standard one. Then if later `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` source will change your class will still be just adding functionality around it.
2. When you call `ChannelHandlerContext` directly you are replacing original implementation. So it will be completely independent of base class method changes.